# How to make working tooltip plugin at the star rating plugin

Tags: jquery, rating-system, tooltipster

I've used [this star rating plugin](https://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/star-rating/). There is appearing a default tooltip if hovering on the each star icon. I want use this [tooltip](http://iamceege.github.io/tooltipster/) instead of that default tooltip. I've put all the necessary files and make the HTML like this way:

```
<input class="hover-star tooltip" type="radio" name="rating-1" value="3" title="OK"/>
```

But, it seems that tooltip can't working at that rating plugin. I am not good at javascript. That's why, I don't understand at where should I modify to make the tooltip working. How can I do it? Here is [my fiddle work](http://jsfiddle.net/learner73/g95s7h9g/2/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rating plugin changes your markup (it adds <a> tag with your title inside). So just adjust your selector like this:

```
$('.tooltip a').tooltipster({
    interactive: true,
    contentAsHTML: true,
});
```

See working [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/g95s7h9g/1/).

**Edit:**
Since <a> tag title is removed by Tooltipster, you can use a little different selector to get tooltip text:

```
...
focus: function(value, link){
  var tip = $('.hover-test');
  tip[0].data = tip[0].data || tip.html();
  tip.html($(link).parent().attr('aria-label') || 'value: '+value);
},
...
```

This is not very clean, but should do the job. See updated [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/g95s7h9g/3/).

Comment: at your fiddle, the right side value is changed. At previous it showed the title of each icon. But, after tooltip working, it's showing now value. I don't understand why, it's changed!

Comment: @user1896653, yes, tooltipster removes the title from `a` tag. Well, we can workaround this, see my updated answer.

Comment: This will help. Thanks.